# HTTP request times out with PECL HTTP

Tags: php, httprequest, pecl

I've been running a server that has been sending HTTP requests using PECL HTTP like so:

```
$http_req = new HttpRequest("http://www.mysite.com/index.php?option=blah");
```

I never had a problem until recently where it has been dropping the requests. Oddly it sends most but still misses a bunch. I recently changed over servers so a whole new install of everything. Although special care has been taken to keep everything the same version as the previous server.

If I dig into the error with this code (to catch the inner exception...credit to [Mark](http://www.mkfoster.com/2009/01/06/how-to-pecl-http-request-exception-and-error-handling/)):

```
$http_req = new HttpRequest("http://www.mysite.com/index.php?option=blah");

try {
    $http_req->send();
} catch (HttpException $ex) {
    if (isset($ex->innerException)){
        echo $ex->innerException->getMessage();
        exit;
    } else {
        echo $ex;
        exit;
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> Timeout was reached; Resolving timed out after 3536 milliseconds
>   (http://www.mysite.com/index.php?option=blah)

Any ideas of what might be going on or what I can try? I did try some options. i.e.

```
$http_req = new HttpRequest("http://www.mysite.com/index.php?option=blah");
$http_req->setOptions(array(timeout=>100));
```

But no change no matter what I try with timeout.

Comment: increase the timeout, use a better dns, pre-resolve and cache the ip, one or or all 3

Comment: @Dagon which timeout? I tried increasing as above with no effect